# How do I check if my element has been focussed in a unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following directive to autofocus a field:

```
.directive('ngAutofocus', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm) {
                $timeout(function () {
                elm[0].focus();
            });
        }
    };
}
```

How would I unit test this? I tried several things like the following selector but they all return errors or false:

```
console.log($(elm[0]).is(':focus'));
```

My unit test is set up like this:

```
elm = angular.element('<input type="text"  name="textfield1" ng-autofocus>');
$scope.$digest();
$compile(elm)($scope);
```

Comment: Besides the remarks you make in your answer, readers should note your directive definition should read: `.directive('ngAutofocus', '$timeout', function ($timeout) {`  -- otherwise `$timeout` is not transcluded by Angular.

Comment: Are you sure? You probably mean with a [ added too, and not because transclusion but because of minification causing injection to break without it with certain minimizers. See https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#minification-and-annotation

Comment: yes to the `[` - I should edit outside the comment box.

Comment: then still, the injection helping is only needed in certain cases, and not required for the question

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I figured it out, and it was pretty obvious actually;

```
it('should set the focus on timeout', function () {
    spyOn(elm[0],'focus');
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(elm[0].focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

My problem was two-fold:

1. I wasn't calling the timeout flush function so timeout wasn't occuring, and
2. I was trying to look at the focus attribute of the element whereas just looking at the call of the focus() function is much more like unit-testing. The focus attribute is something that really belongs to the e2e testing territory.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `document.activeElement` to check focus. The only downside being that the HTML needs to be added to the document body for this to work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Comment: great option, should expand your post on the specifics!

Answer (score 0):

A more verbose solution below, which allows testing (spying on) the focus that runs immediately (i.e. no `$timeout` or other event). The key is to first render a `DOM element` before `$compile` runs:

```
'use strict';

describe('Testing the focus call from the link function', function () {

    var $compile;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('auto-focus-module'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {

        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

    }));

    it('should automatically focus when calling the link function', function () {

        var $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        // create an uncompiled DOM element so we can bind the focus spy
        var rawEl = angular.element('<input auto-focus-directive>');

        // set the spy
        spyOn(rawEl[0], 'focus');

        // compile the rawEl so that compile and link functions run
        $compile(rawEl)($scope);

        expect(rawEl[0].focus).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });

});
```

With a `directive` and `link` function that could look like:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('auto-focus-module')
        .directive('autoFocusDirective', autoFocusDirective);

    function autoFocusDirective () {

        return {
            link: link
        };

        function link (scope, elem) {

            elem[0].focus();

        }

    }

})();
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use the angular.element api - jQuery lite - and use the method triggerHandler().

```
it('should have focus', function() {
    elm.triggerHandler('focus');
    expect(elm).toBeInFocus() //PSEUDO CODE - you will need to see how this can be tested
}
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/

Potential Area for some testing focus knowledge:

https://shanetomlinson.com/2014/test-element-focus-javascript

Also you concerning your unit test - you don't need to append the element to the body, it's possible to test without that.