# Test directive that sets focus

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Directive:

```
angular
    .module('tdsapp')
    .directive('focus', focus);

focus.$inject = ['$timeout'];

// Used to set focus on element
function focus($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: { focus: '@'},
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('focus',
              function (value) {
                  if (value) {
                      $timeout(function () {
                          element[0].focus();
                          console.log('focus called');
                      });
                  }
              }
            );
        }
    };
```

Test Spec:
describe('directive: focus', function () {

```
var $timeout, element, $scope, $compile;
beforeEach(function () {
    module('tdsapp');

    inject(function (_$timeout_, $rootScope, _$compile_) {
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
});

it('should call focus on element', function () {
    var elm = angular.element('<input type="text" name="second" focus="true" />');

    spyOn(elm[0], 'focus');
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(elm[0].focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});

I have looked at [AngularJS: how to test directive which gives focus to element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633684/angularjs-how-to-test-directive-which-gives-focus-to-element) and at [How do I check if my element has been focussed in a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330098/how-do-i-check-if-my-element-has-been-focussed-in-a-unit-test) and neither works. I either get the expect failing or $timeout.flush() - No deferred tasks to be flushed.

EDIT:

As I stated in the text - the above two examples do not work.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: how to test directive which gives focus to element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633684/angularjs-how-to-test-directive-which-gives-focus-to-element) The answer clearly states that the element needs to be compiled with the $compile service.