# Mock document.activeElement in Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following function:

```
  function focusIsNotInInput() {
    // If the element currently in focus is of a certain type, then the key handler shouldn't run
    var currentlyInFocus = $window.document.activeElement;

    var blacklist = ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA', 'BUTTON', 'SELECT', 'IFRAME', 'MD-OPTION'];
    return !blacklist.some(function (nodeName) {
      return nodeName === currentlyInFocus.nodeName;
    });
  }
```

And I need to mock that the element currently in focus is of one of the specified types, but can't get it to work.

I've tried injecting window, like this:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    var $windowMock;
    inject(function(_$window_) {
      $windowMock = _$window_;
      $windowMock.document.activeElement.nodeName = 'INPUT';
    });
  });
```

But when the code above runs, the active element is always still `body`. It's getting overwritten. I have also tried creating an element and setting focus on it:

```
    var elementInFocus = $('<input>');
    this.elem.append(elementInFocus);
    elementInFocus.triggerHandler('focus');
    elementInFocus.focus();
```

But it's the same, `body` is always in focus, what ever I do.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with this too, a possible solution (worked for me) is to add a `spyOn(element, 'focus')` -- here's a reference: [How do I check if my element has been focussed in a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330098/how-do-i-check-if-my-element-has-been-focussed-in-a-unit-test)

My successful solution:

```
  const htmlItem = fixture.nativeElement;
  const searchBar = htmlItem.querySelector('.search-box');
  let focusSpy = spyOn(searchBar, 'focus');
  searchBar.focus();
  expect(focusSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```